# XAML ProgressBar is blue and thin in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, progress-bar

I want to create an Indeterminate progress bar that keeps on loading until a certain task finishes. However, it currently does not look like the default progress bar that I knew, colored green and thick, even though I haven't made any changes in this regard. This is how it looks:

[actual dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SSwl2.png)

```
<Window x:Class="Contributor.AnalyticsSyncDialog"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" mc:Ignorable="d"
    WindowStyle="None" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" Height="70" Width="250" Background="#EEEEEE" Loaded="AnalyticsSync_OnLoaded" >
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Text="Saving Components..." Height="18" Margin="5" Background="Transparent"/>
    <ProgressBar x:Name="Bar" IsIndeterminate="True" Background="Transparent" Grid.Row="1" Height = "5" Margin="5,10"/>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

Moreover, the preview within the designer looks as I'd expect it to be.

[expected dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L0LVB.png)

What could be the cause of this discrepancy?

Comment: Increasing `Height` property didn't solves issue? What OS did you use?

Comment: I increased it to 10, didn't help. Also, I am using Windows 10 Pro, version 20H2.

Comment: Do you use a theming library? You can try to set the Style to null: `<ProgressBar Style="{x:Null}" />`

Comment: @BionicCode no, I do not use a theming library. I also did as you suggested and nothing changed. The thing is, that the exact same code worked before. It broke after I merged code from another branch. I might as well check on another machine if it works the same, I suppose?

Comment: Something in your application is overriding the default Style, obviously.

Comment: You can check the App.xaml file if there are some theme resources loaded.

Comment: Is there a way to prevent that from happening? Except for that `Style="..."` already mentioned and also looking for the thing that is overriding my style.

Comment: There is no such file as App.xaml on a project or solution level.

Comment: Why don't you ask the author of the version you have merged?

Comment: There is always a App.xaml file. It's in the startup project and has a global scope.

Comment: Plenty of changesets happened in the meanwhile and none of them related to WPF OR related to the project I'm looking into. Hence I figured that I might as well not dig into it much.

Comment: But obviously somebody has changed the GUI design/theme of your application. I don't think SO is the right place to solve your problem. Ask your team.

Comment: Alrighty. Haven't thought of it being an issue outside of my own code until now. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: No, it seems to be a global theme that replaces the default theme. I don't think that the default look is wanted. So before forcing to overrride the current theming you must discuss it with the project lead.

Comment: I agree with @BionicCode. Check your global theme settings. App.xaml, or if you have Shell.xaml, there must be default theme